# Re-run Ajax with data from its own response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to insert into ajax post some altered variable from its own success data?

On page load, first ajax fires and shows some records from mysql, then I take last record ID and store it in `latestID`, next second ajax fires and retrieves only records from that ID forward and then stores the lastId and fires again.

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ ... }}',
        dataType: 'json',
        'success': function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
    function callback(response) {
        var idList = [];
        var printer_category = response.printer.productcategory_id;
        var printer_timer = parseInt(response.printer.timer);
        var printer_storeid = response.printer.store_id;
        var printer_physicalPrint = parseInt(response.printer.physical_print);
        var printer_id = parseInt(response.printer.id);
        var data = response.transactions;
        console.log(response);
        $.each(data, function (i, dataitem) {
            console.log(dataitem);
            idList.push(dataitem.id);
        });
        var latestID = Math.max.apply(Math, idList);


        function getData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ ... }}',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {latestID: latestID, printer_timer: printer_timer, printer_storeid: printer_storeid, printer_category: printer_category},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    data = data.transactions;
                    if (data != 0) {
                        var idList = [];
                        $.each(data, function (i, dataitem) {
                            console.log(dataitem);
                            idList.push(dataitem.id);
                        });
                        var latestID = Math.max.apply(Math, idList);
                        console.log(latestID);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        getData();
        setInterval(function () {
            getData();
        }, 10000); 

   }

});
```

If I `console.log(latestID)` inside the `success: function` it shows the correct value, but ajax posts `data: {latestID: latestID}`, value `1` on each `setInterval` run.

*EDIT: added entire code.

Comment: Is this your exact and only code?

Comment: No, I can post it, but before can you please tell me if this part is correct and if it should work?

Comment: latestID is global in this scenerio, so should be right i think

Comment: this should work as latestID is global, try to log values on both occasion and post those log values here

Comment: I added the entire code maybe I am doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: remove var from this line "var latestID = Math.max.apply(Math, idList);"

Comment: In the `success` callback. Remove `var`.

Comment: It works, that was the problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Always useful to post code that matches - the edit doesn't match the original as the original didn't have the second `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `var latestID = Math.max.apply(Math, idList);`

use `latestID = Math.max.apply(Math, idList);` in success callback.

using var before the variable declares a method level variable overriding the value of global variable. As you want to keep on using the latestID, you need to have global variable.

Comment: Specify in the success callback of the Ajax inside `getData()`. The first one above the `getData()` function is correct!

Comment: Done, basically i pointed to the exact code which needed to be changed but mentioned callback as well.